# Отправка почты Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

Нужно сделать отправку письма владельцам сайта с почтой клиента, когда на странице с подпиской на новости клиент заполняет поле email и нажимает кнопку "подписаться на новости".

В контроллере mailers/subscribes_mailer.rb

```
class SubscribesMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "boss@yandex.ru",
            template_path: 'mailers/subscribes'

    def subscribe
        mail to: 'boss@yandex.ru',
        subject: "new subscribe"
    end
end
```

В view, где находится форма отправки:

```
    <section class="one-half">
        <h2>Подписаться на новости</h2>
        <div id="newsletter-wrap">
            <p>После подписки на новостную рассылку на ваш e-mail будут приходить все актуальные новости и акции компании. Вы в любой момент сможете отписаться от рассылки.</p>
            <div class="notification-box notification-box-success" style="display: none;">
                <p>Вы успешно подписаны на новостную рассылку. Проверьте почтовый ящик для подтверждения.</p>
                <a href="#" class="notification-close notification-close-success">x</a>
            </div>
            <div class="notification-box notification-box-error" style="display: none;">
                <p>Ваш почтовый ящик не может быть добавлен в список рассылки. Пожалуйста повторите запрос позже.</p>
                <a href="#" class="notification-close notification-close-error">x</a>
            </div>
            <form id="newsletter-form" class="content-form clearfix" action="#" method="post">

                <%= button_to "Добавить", SubscribesMailer.subscribe, :class => 'button' %>
                <input id="newsletter" type="email" name="newsletter" placeholder="Введите свой e-mail адрес &hellip;" class="required">
            </form>
            <p class="tip"><span class="note">&#42;</span>Если письмо не приходит, проверьте папку спам в Вашем почтовом ящике.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

При обновлении страницы - получаю ошибку:

```
undefined method `SubscribesMailer' for SubscribesMailer:Class
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать отправку письма с сайта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаем модель контроллер и представление Subscriber с одной колонкой в таблице - email, в которой будут храниться все почтовые адреса пользователей подписавшихся на рассылку командой:

```
rails g scaffold Subscriber email:string
```

В модели Subscriber добавляем валидацию при записи значений в базу данных которая проверяет наличие и уникальность email'а который будет помещен в базу данных:

```
validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

Создаем mailer командой:

```
rails g mailer subscribe_mailer
```

В subscribe_mailer.rb изменяем адрес отправителя на тот который нужен:

```
default from: "admin@site.com"
```

Добавляем метод subscribe_email, который в качестве параметра принимает subscriber, созданный ранее и с помощью метода mail отправляет письмо пользователю на адрес который находился в subscriber.email.

```
def subscribe_email(subscriber)
   @subscriber = subscriber
   mail(to: @subscriber.email, subject: "New subscriber", cc: "admin@site.com"
end
```

Параметр "bсс", позволяет отправить скрытую копию письма владельцам ресурса.

В views/subscribe_mailer/ создаем два файла: subscribe_email.html.erb и subscribe_email.text.erb c содержимым писем отправляемых пользователям.

В метод create контроллера subscribers_controller добавляем строчку:

```
SubscribeMailer.subscribe_email(@subscriber).deliver
```

которая отправляет письмо если запись добавлена в базу данных.

В представление добавляем форму ввода:

```
<%= form_for :subscriber, url: subscribers_url do |form| %>
<%= form.submit %>
<%= form.email_field :email %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы на абсолютно неверном пути: mailers/subscribes_mailer.rb это не контроллер, это (внезапно!) мейлер. У вас не четкого понимания последовательности действий, поэтому код в вашем вопросе делу не поможет.
Как это работет:

Самый простой вариант - у нас одна подписка на новости, поэтому в таблице users (или кто у вас является получателем) добавляем столбец send_news:boolean. Теперь у нас есть понятие подписчиков (пользователи, у которых send_news в значении true). Галку send_news выводим на форму -- отдельную или просто в профайле юзера. Само собой, у юзера есть email.

Создаем таблицу с новостями, там будем писать новости. Таблицу лучше назвать articles, а модель Article, поскольку news бывают только во множественном числе, а `new` к тому же служебное слово. У новостей будет текст и название.

Создаем мейлер, которым будем рассылать новости.

```
class ArticlesMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'newsmaker@dobermann-site.com'

  def article_mail(subscriber_id, subject, article)
    @subscriber = User.find subscriber_id  
    @article = article   
    mail(to: @subscriber.email, subject: "We have news! #{subject}")
  end
end
```

Далее создаем разметку для писем:

```
#app/views/articles_mailerarticles_mail.html.haml
!!! 5

%html
  %body
    %h1= @article.title
    %p= @article.text
```

Ну и теперь нужна фоновая задача, которая это все отправляет после создания новой статьи. Смотрите в сторону delayed_job. Вкратце -- выбираете юзеров, которые хотят получать новости, потом перебираете их и создаете новый мейл для каждого, delayed-job в фоне отправляет.

Comment: Добавлю только, что с версии 4.2 рельс есть ActiveJob для фоновых задач.

Comment: У меня нету пользователей на сайте. Достаточно просто письмо отправлять владельцам сайта о том, что такой-то email адрес подписался на рассылку. Рассылка будет вестись не с сайта а с почты владельцев (коммерческие предложения всякие как я понял).

Comment: Вам в любом случае нужно  эти адреса где-то хранить. В этом случае просто создаете таблицу Subscriber, в ней храните адреса для рассылки. Когда появляется новость для рассылки, перебираете эта таблицу и создаете письма.